# Changing Coordinates on a Quadric

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Suppose we have a quadric of the form

$$a_1x^2 + b_2y + b_3z + c = 0$$

with $a_1 \neq 0$. How do we see that if $b_2$ and $b_3$ are not both zero, then by rotating the quadric so that the $y$-axis ends up parallel to $(b_2, b_3)$ in the $yz$-plane, we end up with an equation of the same form, with $b_2 \neq 0$ and $b_3 = 0$?

I hope I have this correct; this comes from Pressley's "Elementary Differential Geometry," page 102. There he says "$xz$-plane" instead of my "$yz$-plane," but I have to imagine this is a typo unless I am misunderstanding the situation.